# ElasticSearch - fuzzyQuery Java API response are almost same as matchQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fuzzy-search

Am trying to fetch documents from elastic search using using `matchQuery` & `fuzzyQuery` but am getting same count of response for both the API.

For example :

Scenario 1 ( with matchQuery )

Am search for valve using matchQuery and am getting the count of `36` with the below `matchQuery` API

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("catalog_value", "valve"))
                       .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US" ));
```

If i search for `valves` also am getting only `14` count.

Scenario 2 ( with fuzzyQuery )

Am search for valve using fuzzyQuery and am getting the count of `34` with the below `fuzzyQuery` API

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                      .must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("catalog_value", "valve"))
                      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US"));
```

If i search for `valves` also am getting only `14` count. Actually, am expecting both `valve` & `valves` should give same count if we use the fuzzyQuery.

Anyone have any idea about fuzzyQuery API.

Am using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version.

Sample document which matches `valves`.

```
    {  
    "_index":"catalog",
    "_type":"doc",
    "_id":"517yxmQB1-MO2Tblt7C3",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":{  
       "catalog_name":"family451",
       "catalog_value":"These control valves range with actuation choices featuring.",
       "catalog_id":41065,
       "@version":"1",
       "locale":"en_US",
       "@timestamp":"2018-07-23T11:42:29.751Z"
}
```

Please find my mapping details :

```
        PUT catalog
    {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
           "value_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
           ],
           "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
         }
       }
     }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "catalog_value": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "value_analyzer"
          },
          "catalog_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
         "catalog_name":{
         "type":"keyword"
         },
         "locale":{
         "type":"keyword"
         }

        }
       }
      }
}
```

**Update**

I have tested with the following scenarios and i got the below count.

```
valve    --> 17
valves   --> 7
valvess  --> 7
valvesss --> 8

val      --> 17
valv     --> 17
```

**Update 2**

With the below modified query and getting the below result count.

```
QueryBuilder qb1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("catalog_attr_value", "valve").boost(1.0f).prefixLength(0).fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE).transpositions(true))
            .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("locale", "en_US"));


valve    --> 17
valves   --> 7
valvess  --> 8
valvesss --> 0

val      --> 17
valv     --> 17
```

**UPDATE 3**

With the below fuzzyQuery am not getting proper result count for `valve` & `Valves`.

```
QueryBuilder qb1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("product_attr_value", keyword).boost(1.0f).prefixLength(0).fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO).transpositions(true));
```

for, `valve` & `valves` search i got totally 10 result count (am restricting the count to 10 ) and none of the documents are matched together.

For example, below are the ids i got for `valve` & `valves` search

valve :

```
17194
219575
219574
280638
282288
298177
295626
4112
219069
219381
```

Sample response for `valve` search

```
"hits":[  
     {  
        "_index":"product_offering",
        "_type":"doc",
        "_id":"kE89_2QBfp1CuLwJxs-W",
        "_score":3.0630755,
        "_source":{  
           "product_status":"ACT",
           "@timestamp":"2018-08-03T10:03:12.194Z",
           "product_code":"M9000-560",
           "std_delivery_time":0,
           "product_attr_type":null,
           "label":"long_description",
           "product_attr_value":"Ball Valve Linkage Kit for applying M9203 and M9208 Series Actuators to VG1000 Series Valves",
           "is_product_visible":1,
           "product_name":"product17167",
           "product_group":"single",
           "product_id":17194,
           "@version":"1",
           "catalog_id":264,
           "locale":"en_US",
           "expiration_date":null,
           "product_type":"accessory",
           "min_order_quantity":1,
           "product_attr_name":"product17167_long_description"
        }
     },
```

Valves :

```
15680
15572
15599
15615
15674
15650
15526
15543
6869
6868
```

Sample response for `valves` search  ( which is not available when am searching for `valve`)

```
"hits":[  
     {  
        "_index":"product_offering",
        "_type":"doc",
        "_id":"A089_2QBfp1CuLwJ-d9C",
        "_score":3.8922772,
        "_source":{  
           "product_status":"DSC",
           "@timestamp":"2018-08-03T10:03:26.343Z",
           "product_code":"M9116-GDC-1N2",
           "std_delivery_time":0,
           "product_attr_type":null,
           "label":"long_description",
           "product_attr_value":"These electric actuators have been specially designed for the motorised operation of various types of water valves and fittings such as mixing valves, butterfly valves and ball valves.",
           "is_product_visible":0,
           "product_name":"product4459",
           "product_group":"single",
           "product_id":15680,
           "@version":"1",
           "catalog_id":319,
           "locale":"en_US",
           "expiration_date":null,
           "product_type":"legacy",
           "min_order_quantity":1,
           "product_attr_name":"product4459_long_description"
        }
     },
```

Comment: What version of ElasticSearch are you using?

Comment: I'm interested to see a document that isn't returned when querying `valves` using fuzziness even though it should be.

Comment: @Nick - Am using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version.

Comment: @Val - Am not sure., either am forming the fuzzyQuery properly or not.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that match please?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but can you specify `prefix_length` on the fuzzy query?  The default is zero and it might lead to the results you are seeing.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: @Val - I have updated one sample document, which matches `valves`

Comment: Can you also share your mapping please?

Comment: @Val - updated my mapping details.

Comment: Why the document you shared doesn't match the mapping you're showing? There's no `catalog_value` field in the document.

Comment: @val- sorry, i have updated the proper response document.

Comment: @Val - do you have any thought like., why `valve` & `valves` giving different different result count.

Comment: Earlier you mentioned that `valves` gave 14 results, why now 7?

Comment: Sorry, i was confused and searched in wrong indexes., after that i made one separate index for testing., and whatever count is mentioned here is the proper one.

Comment: Can you share a document that is returned by your match query that is not returned by your fuzzy query?

Comment: @MorbidGnome actually am having more than 200K documents in my index., am not sure how can I share it

Comment: Is there any minimum best practice for using fuzzyQuery